# Meld as diff tool in gitk in Windows

Tags: windows, git, gitk, meld

I am always annoyed when I use *gitk* an it forces me to configure a separate diff tool.
Now while this works fine for me in Linux, it is an absolute hell on Windows. I am trying to use *Meld*, so I wrote a *.bat*, for mapping parameters:

```
meld.exe %2 %5
```

Sadly *gitk* does not print anything to stdout or stderr and it just does not work.
Has anyone gotten *Meld* working on *gitk* on *Windows*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recent version of *meld* now worked for me. Had to fix some bugs.